# Laravel FormRequests do not seem to use middleware

Tags: php, laravel, http, middleware, lumen

When validating input via `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` it seems to skip any middleware that we are applying.

We have the following middleware in our `kernal.php`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\RequestTransformer::class,
    // ...
];
```

The middleware is called, although none of the transformations we apply to input are seen within the `FormRequest` in the controller. Are `FormRequest`'s actually the same HTTP stack as our middleware? It seems to be different.

## UPDATE

After further investigation FormReqests do not actually pass through middleware. They are initialize very early on via the root `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` request object. Thus missing any middleware. Why? no idea... seems counter intuitive to not be passing a form request through middleware... One would assume middleware is just that: effecting ALL incoming requests.

Comment: Have you apply the middleware in your route/controller?
https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware

Comment: which version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: The middleware is a global middleware. We can see that it runs, although does not modify the FormRequest. Laravel 5.2.x